# How to transpose some values in rows to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, transpose

I have a table storing people's shift information. Its structure is:

```
SHIFT_TABLE
-----------
ShiftID  PeopleID  ShiftDate   ShiftStart         ShiftEnd
1        41        2020-08-24  2020-08-24 06:00   2020-08-24 14:00
2        41        2020-08-26  2020-08-26 06:00   2020-08-26 14:00
3        41        2020-08-27  2020-08-27 19:00   2020-08-28 03:00
4        41        2020-08-29  2020-08-29 10:00   2020-08-29 16:00
5        58        2020-08-24  2020-08-24 14:00   2020-08-24 21:30
6        58        2020-08-25  2020-08-25 14:00   2020-08-25 23:00
7        58        2020-08-30  2020-08-30 08:00   2020-08-30 18:00

Columns     Data types
-------     ----------
ShiftDate   date
ShiftStart  datetime
ShiftEnd    datetime
```

User will only send one date (without time) and the new stored procedure will return shift information of all people for that week (from Sunday to Saturday). So, if use selects any date, say Monday or Wednesday, from one week, result will be exactly the same.

For example, if user sends `2020-08-25` to SP, all rows will be returned except row with ShiftID as 7.

When sending `2020-08-25`, the result should look like this:

```
Person  2020-08-23  2020-08-24   2020-08-25   2020-08-26   2020-08-27   2020-08-28  2020-08-29
41      OFF         06:00-14:00  OFF          06:00-14:00  19:00-03:00  OFF         10:00-16:00
58      OFF         14:00-21:30  14:00-21:30  OFF          OFF          OFF         OFF
```

Instead of dates as column names, I am fine if day names are used since this approach may avoid dynamic SQL:

```
Person  Sunday  Monday       Tuesday      Wednesday    Thursday     Friday  Saturday
41      OFF     06:00-14:00  OFF          06:00-14:00  19:00-03:00  OFF     10:00-16:00
58      OFF     14:00-21:30  14:00-21:30  OFF          OFF          OFF     OFF
```

I want to avoid dynamic SQL or XML [solutions](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/). I can get the weekday number (1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday etc.). I am not sure if that will be helpful. Is there a way to transpose only `ShiftStart` and `ShiftEnd` columns with `PoepleID`. I can already filter the result set by `ShiftDate`. Column names will change for every week. There are several suggestions for dynamic SQL which I want to avoid at all costs.

There may be some way to do it using pivot, but it appears to be a slower method.

Comment: If you want the column names to be actual dates in the data, then you will need dynamic SQL.  If you are okay with "Mon", "Tue" and so on, then you can get around that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am fine with "Mon", "Tue" etc. or even simpler just weekday numbers, like 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Is ShiftDate a 'date' type column?  Are ShiftStart, ShiftEnd datetime?

Comment: @SteveC Yes. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Comment: The datetime doesn't implicitly convert.  When I run "declare @ShiftStart         datetime='2020.08.24 0600';" the message is "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."  Are you sure it's datetime?  It would be simpler if it were already a string

Comment: @SteveC Yes, you are right. I should have written as `2020-08-24 06:00`.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

If you don't want to use dynamic sql and are OK with having *"Monday, Tuesday...Sunday"* (Or the number equivalent for each day 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday...)  as column headers instead of actual date values like **"2020.08.23  2020.08.24  2020.08.25  2020.08.26  2020.08.27  2020.08.28  2020.08.29"** then your requirements are achievable:

**The query**

```
declare @WorkDate date = '2020.08.25', @StartFilter date, @EndFilter date

declare @shift_table table ( ShiftID int identity(1,1), PeopleID int, ShiftDate varchar(max), ShiftStart datetime, ShiftEnd datetime )
insert into @shift_table (PeopleID, ShiftDate, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd )
      select 41,        '2020.08.24',  '2020-08-24 06:00',   '2020-08-24 14:00'
union select 41,        '2020.08.26',  '2020-08-26 06:00',   '2020-08-26 14:00'
union select 41,        '2020.08.27',  '2020-08-27 19:00',   '2020-08-28 03:00'
union select 41,        '2020.08.29',  '2020-08-29 10:00',   '2020-08-29 16:00'
union select 58,        '2020.08.24',  '2020-08-24 14:00',   '2020-08-24 21:30'
union select 58,        '2020.08.25',  '2020-08-25 14:00',   '2020-08-25 23:00'
union select 58,        '2020.08.30',  '2020-08-30 08:00',   '2020-08-30 18:00'

-- get the week start and end date filters based on the @WorkDate passed in
SELECT @StartFilter =  DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @WorkDate)-1), @WorkDate) /* week start */,
       @EndFilter = DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @WorkDate)), @WorkDate) /* week end */

select
    Person,
    min(Monday) as [Monday],
    min(Tuesday) as [Tuesday],
    min(Wednesday) as [Wednesday], 
    min(Thursday) as [Thursday], 
    min(Friday) as [Friday], 
    min(Saturday) as [Saturday], 
    min(Sunday) as [Sunday]
from (
    select
        PeopleID as Person,
        isnull([Monday],'OFF') as [Monday],
        isnull([Tuesday],'OFF') as [Tuesday],
        isnull([Wednesday],'OFF') as [Wednesday],
        isnull([Thursday],'OFF') as [Thursday],
        isnull([Friday],'OFF') as [Friday],
        isnull([Saturday],'OFF') as [Saturday],
        isnull([Sunday],'OFF') as [Sunday]
    from (
    select
        *,
        DATENAME(dw,cast(ShiftDate as date)) [Day],
        format(ShiftStart,'HHmm','en-us') + '-' + format(ShiftEnd,'HHmm','en-us') ShiftTime
    from @shift_table
    where cast(ShiftDate as date) between @StartFilter and @EndFilter
    ) src
    pivot
    (
        max(ShiftTime)
        for [Day] in ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])
    ) piv
) P
group by P.Person
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE SHIFT_TABLE
(
    ShiftID  INT,
    PeopleID  INT, 
    ShiftDate Date,
    ShiftStart DATETIME,
    ShiftEnd DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO SHIFT_Table
VALUES
(1, 41, '2020-08-24', '2020-08-24 06:00', '2020-08-24 14:00'),
(2, 41, '2020-08-26', '2020-08-26 06:00', '2020-08-26 14:00'),
(3, 41, '2020-08-27', '2020-08-27 19:00', '2020-08-28 03:00'),
(4, 41, '2020-08-29', '2020-08-29 10:00', '2020-08-29 16:00'),
(5, 58, '2020-08-24', '2020-08-24 14:00', '2020-08-24 21:30'),
(6, 58, '2020-08-25', '2020-08-25 14:00', '2020-08-25 23:00'),
(7, 58, '2020-08-30', '2020-08-30 08:00', '2020-08-30 18:00')
```

**Query**

```
  DECLARE @userdate DATE = '2020-08-25'
  


SELECT PeopleID,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Sunday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Sunday) END AS Sunday,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Monday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Monday) END AS Monday,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Tuesday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Tuesday) END AS Tuesday,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Wednesday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Wednesday) END AS Wednesday,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Thursday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Thursday) END AS Thursday,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Friday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Friday) END AS Friday,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Saturday) = '' THEN 'OFF' ELSE Max(Saturday) END AS Saturday
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        PeopleId,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 1 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Sunday,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 2 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Monday,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 3 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Tuesday,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 4 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Wednesday,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 5 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Thursday,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 6 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Friday,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,ShiftDate) = 7 THEN FORMAT(SHIFTSTart, 'HHmm') + '-' + FORMAT(ShiftEnd, 'HHmm') ELSE '' END AS Saturday
    FROM SHIFT_TABLE
    WHERE DATEPART(Week, ShiftDate) = DATEPART(Week, @UserDate)
) s
GROUP BY PeopleID
```

**Results**

```
PeopleID    Sunday  Monday    Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday    Friday Saturday
41          OFF     0600-1400 OFF       0600-1400   1900-0300   OFF    1000-1600
58          OFF     1400-2130 1400-2300 OFF         OFF         OFF    OFF
```

Comment: The results for Friday dont seem to be correct. Friday is 8-28 and in the example expected result both PeopleID are shown as **OFF**. Your results show `1900-0300` for **PeopleID** *41* on Friday. There is also a problem with the result for Monday. Your results show both **PeopleID** as OFF but both had shifts.

Comment: @vvvv4d yes you are right I had day of week incorrectly zero based rather than 1 based, now fixed

Answer (score 1):

This approach converts @userdate into a wk_start date and uses it to create the pivot table with conditional aggregation.

Data

```
CREATE TABLE test_TABLE
(
    ShiftID  INT,
    PeopleID  INT, 
    ShiftDate Date,
    ShiftStart DATETIME,
    ShiftEnd DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO test_TABLE
VALUES
(1, 41, '2020-08-24', '2020-08-24 06:00', '2020-08-24 14:00'),
(2, 41, '2020-08-26', '2020-08-26 06:00', '2020-08-26 14:00'),
(3, 41, '2020-08-27', '2020-08-27 19:00', '2020-08-28 03:00'),
(4, 41, '2020-08-29', '2020-08-29 10:00', '2020-08-29 16:00'),
(5, 58, '2020-08-24', '2020-08-24 14:00', '2020-08-24 21:30'),
(6, 58, '2020-08-25', '2020-08-25 14:00', '2020-08-25 23:00'),
(7, 58, '2020-08-30', '2020-08-30 08:00', '2020-08-30 18:00');
```

Query

```
declare @userdate   DATE='2020-08-25';
declare @wk_int     int=datediff(wk, 0, @userdate);
declare @wk_start   date=dateadd(d, -1, dateadd(wk, @wk_int, 0)); 


SELECT PeopleID,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=0 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF') as Sunday,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=1 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF') as Monday,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=2 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF') as Tuesday,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=3 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF') as Wednesday,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=4 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF') as Thursday,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=5 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF')as Friday,
       isnull(max(case when datediff(d, @wk_start, t.ShiftDate)=6 then tm.hrs else null end), 'OFF') as Saturday
FROM
  test_TABLE t
  cross apply
  (select concat_ws('-', replace(convert(char(5),cast(ShiftStart as time)), ':', ''),
                         replace(convert(char(5),cast(ShiftEnd as time)), ':', '')) hrs) tm
where ShiftDate>=@wk_start 
      and ShiftDate<=dateadd(d, 7, @wk_start)
group by
  peopleid;
```

Results

```
PeopleID    Sunday  Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday
41          OFF     0600-1400   OFF         0600-1400   1900-0300   OFF     1000-1600
58          OFF     1400-2130   1400-2300   OFF         OFF         OFF      OFF
```

Comment: If IIF is preferred over CASE WHEN i'll gladly update this